# I want to get title name of post, but i didn't get by this code. Any suggestion?

Tags: posts, wp-query

```
add_shortcode('sort_featured_restaurant','sort_featured');
function sort_featured(){

 $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

 // The Loop
 if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
   echo '<ul>';
   while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    $the_query->the_post();
    echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
   }
   echo '</ul>';
  } else {
  // no posts found
 }
// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();

 if(!$wp_query) {
        global $wp_query;
    }

 $args = array(
  'post_type' => 'food',
  'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num',
  'meta_key'  => 'listing_price',
  'order'  => 'DESC'
 );
 $query = new WP_Query( $args );

 query_posts( array_merge( $args , $wp_query->query ) );
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking for here, please edit the question with more details, thanks.

Comment: actually i will get this content which are shown in image.This code will sort them accordiung to their price but by this i can't got title name for each post.

Comment: How are you trying to get the title? What code are you using inside the loop?

Comment: What you are trying to do ? A new query then query_post() doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Firstly, m using this code but they get same result as previous one gives.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'food',
    'orderby'        => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_key'       => 'listing_price',
    'order'          => 'DESC',
    'posts_per_page' => $count,
    'paged'          => $paged,
);

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $loop->have_posts() ):
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : 
        $loop->the_post();
        echo get_the_title();
        echo get_the_content();
    endwhile;
endif;
```

Comment: Code doesn't work.

Comment: It doesn't work because he was missing the `echo` in the entry. I fixed it and it should work now